# Finding $\left | \int_{C} \frac{\sin{(1/z)}} {z^{2}} dz \right| $ over straight line from $z_{1} = i$ till $z_{2} = 2/ \pi $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I need to find $$\left | \int_{C} \frac{\sin{(1/z)}} {z^{2}}  dz \right| $$ where $C$ is the straight line from $z_{1} = i$ till $z_{2} = 2/ \pi $.

Now I would very much like some guidance with this. I see we have a singularity at $z_{0} =0 $, but since this is not on the contour nor enclosed by the contour, I would argue this is not a problem. Also, since $C$ is a straight line I reckon we should use parametrization (not sure though). The line segment can be paramtrized by:
$$ z(t) = i - \frac{\pi}{2}it,$$
with endpoints $t=0$ and $t=\frac{2}{\pi}$

The if we let $f(z) = \frac{\sin{(1/z)}} {z^{2}} $ and we use the fact that $$\int_{C} \frac{\sin{(1/z)}} {z^{2}}  dz = \int_{t_{start}}^{t_{end}} f(z(t)) z'(t) dt $$ we find

$$
\int_{C} \frac{\sin{(1/z)}} {z^{2}}  dz = \int_{C} \frac{\sin{(1/(i - \frac{\pi}{2}it))}} {(i - \frac{\pi}{2}it)^{2}}  dz, $$

but this to me makes the integral only more troublesome. So I reckon I took a wrong turn somewhere.

Comment: Your parameterization is on the imaginary axis for some reason, when it shouldn't be.

Comment: I am very sorry, I made a typo. $z_{1} = i$. But I guess that only changes the values over which to integrate as @NinadMunshi already showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function has an explicit antiderivative

$$\left|\int_C \frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}{z^2}\:dz\right| = \int_{\frac{2}{\pi}}^1 \frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{x^2}\:dx = \cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\Biggr|_{\frac{2}{\pi}}^1 = \cos 1$$

---

$\mathbf{EDIT}$: Sine $z_1$ was really $i$, the answer becomes

$$|\cos(-i)| = \cosh 1$$

Comment: Wow, that makes life a lot easier. Just for my understanding, assume it did not have an explicit antiderivative, would my approach/idea work (forgetting the horrible integral I end up with...) Also: I am sorry, I made a typo. $z_{1}=i$ so I reckon you end up with $cos(-i)-cos(\frac{2}{\pi}) = - cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0$

Comment: @Steven yes it would've worked, but your parameterization was incorrect.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a typo. $z_{1}=i$ so I reckon you end up with $cos(-i)-cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) = cos(-i)$

Comment: @Steven exactly!